# Why Array size in my ContactListener derived class in Libgdx Bullet is always zero?

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx, bulletphysics

I am trying make create a `ContactListener` derived class in Libgdx using Bullet wrapper for collision detection like in this [tutorial](https://xoppa.github.io/blog/using-the-libgdx-3d-physics-bullet-wrapper-part1/) but in separate classes. It separate classes for rendering and game world. In `render()` method of class `Render` I pass an Array of model instances to this derived class. But when I run it gives an because Array size is zero. Here is the derived class :

```
package com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.Helpers;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.ContactListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class CollisionListener extends ContactListener {

    private Array<ModelInstance> instances;

    public CollisionListener() {
        this.instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
    }

    public void setModelInstances(Array<ModelInstance> instances) {
        this.instances = instances;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContactAdded(int userValue0, int partId0, int index0, int userValue1, int partId1, int index1) {
//instances.get(colObj1Wrap.getCollisionObject().getUserValue()).collided = false;error
        Gdx.app.log("instances.size", Integer.toString(instances.size));//zero
        Gdx.app.log("ddhbdfhd", "fhfgjfgj");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the Renderer class:

```
package com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameWorld;

import com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameObjects.Ball;
import com.anutrix.brickbreaker3d.gameObjects.Brick;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Environment;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.ColorAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.environment.DirectionalLight;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.CameraInputController;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.DebugDrawer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionDispatcher;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btCollisionWorld;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btDbvtBroadphase;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.collision.btDefaultCollisionConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.bullet.linearmath.btIDebugDraw;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Disposable;

public class GameRenderer implements Disposable {

    private GameWorld gameWorld;
    private PerspectiveCamera cam;
    public ModelBatch modelBatch;
    private CameraInputController camController;
    private Environment environment;
    public Array<ModelInstance> instances;
    ModelBuilder mb = new ModelBuilder();
    btCollisionDispatcher dispatcher;

    public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
        this.modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
        this.environment = new Environment();
        this.instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();

        gameWorld = world;
        cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(10f, 10f, 0f);
        cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        cam.near = 1f;
        cam.far = 300f;
        cam.update();

        camController = new CameraInputController(cam);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(camController);
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));


    }

    public void render() {
        //Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "render");
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        for (Brick b : gameWorld.bricks) {
            b.getObject().setUserValue(instances.size);
            instances.add(b.getModelInstance());
        }
        for (Ball b : gameWorld.balls) {
            b.getObject().setUserValue(instances.size);
            instances.add(b.getModelInstance());
        }

        gameWorld.collisionListener.setModelInstances(instances);

        modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
        modelBatch.end();

        instances.clear();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        modelBatch.dispose();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Inside `setModelInstances()` the instances.size is correct. But after each call to it, the `instances.size` is equal to 0 .
 Also I wasn't sure of pass by reference(since Java uses pass by value). So is it better(if it works) if I call `setInstances()` just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `CollisionListener#instances` and `GameRenderer#instances` point to the same reference after your call to `gameWorld.collisionListener.setModelInstances(instances);` inside your `GameRenderer#render()` method.

Then, at the end of the method, you are invoking:

```
    instances.clear();
```

This would be clearing out `instances`. So, the size would become 0 when you call `render`.

---

Instead, inside your `setModelInstances` method, you could create a new Array instance like this:

```
public void setModelInstances(Array<ModelInstance> instances) {
    this.instances = new Array<>(instances);
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then how can I replace `instances.clear();` . If I remove that, the number of instances after each loop would just increase.

Comment: @Anutrix you could copy the array in `setModelInstances` (instead of assigning the reference)

Comment: I thought assigning reference would use less space. Also "IF" it would work I could just call `setInstance()` only once.